# chi square test for a fair game in R

Tags: r, chi-squared

i have data from a game. The values are from 1 to 10 and i need to test if that game is a fair game. I have produced a frequency table and i want to make a chi squared test in R.

Based on my understanding the 'fair probability' must be equal to 1/10.

Then i repeat this value 100 times (as the length of my observarions) and i run a chi squared test.

My question is what i am doing wrong and i get the same chi squared and p value when i insert the probabilities and when i dont?

My code is:

```
fair<-1/10
array<-rep(fair,length=100)

chisq.test(Data)

chisq.test(table(Data),p=array)
```

If i dont use the `table(Data)` in the chi square test, then i get the error:

> probabilities must sum to 1.

Comment: What is `Data`?

Answer (score 1):

Does `chisq.test(table(Data), p=array)` work ok? I'd be suprised as `p` needs to have length equal to the length of `table(x)` not `x` as it's a vector of probabilities for the unique observed values. e.g.

```
set.seed(1)
x <- round(runif(100, 0.1, 1), 1)*10
x
p <- rep(1/10, 10)
chisq.test(x=table(x), p=p)

# this errors because of too many probabilities provided
chisq.test(x=table(x), p=rep(1/10, 100))
# Error in chisq.test(x = table(x), p = rep(1/10, 100)) : 
#   'x' and 'p' must have the same number of elements

# this errors because x needs to be the count of observations
chisq.test(x=x, p=rep(1/10, 100))
# Error in chisq.test(x = x, p = rep(1/10, 100)) : 
#   probabilities must sum to 1.
```

edit: added the ones that error

Comment: Is x <- round(runif(100, 0.1, 1), 1)*10
x
p <- rep(1/10, 10)
chisq.test(x=table(x), p=p) Correct? The output of chisq.test(x=table(x), p=p) is the same as the output of chisq.test(x=table(x)), ie without specifying the probabilities. The same holds in my data

Comment: Yeah in this case as it's all proportionally equal it's the same. You can see on the help page in the Usage section at the top if you type `?chisq.test` in the console

Comment: I understand. But my data are not proportionally equal. The numbers from 1 to 10 have different frequency i mean. Therefore i expect the chi square test to be different when i insert the probabilities. In your example try to sample from gamma distribution for ecample